# How can I conditionally copy between Google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to conditional copy a value from one sheet to another.

About the below script:

- It checks if in SOURCE tab the value in column H is equal to 45 and if Column A is empty. If so, it should copy the value in Column G into the last row of column A in TARGET tab. It also ads data to some of the TARGET tab columns
- If I change this: `sourceSheet.getRange(rangeToCopy).copyTo(destination.getRange(destination.getLastRow()+1, 1)),{contentsOnly:true};`
  to this: `sourceSheet.getRange(rangeToCopy).copyTo(destination.getRange(destination.getLastRow()-1, 1)),{contentsOnly:true};` the cell is pasted on Column A on the penultimate row, which makes me think that the present code tries to copy to a row after the last visible one instead of pasting into the next blank cell after a non blank one in Column A, hence returning the error explained on the next bullet
- As is, it returns the error: *The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet*. (I understood that the problem is because of the use of getlasrow and being used as is, it's trying to retrieve a row that does not exist)

This is the code so far:

```
 function CopyTo(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("SOURCE");
  var destination = sheet.getSheetByName("TARGET");
  var lastRow = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();

  for(var row=3; row<=lastRow; row++){
  if(sourceSheet.getRange(row,1).getValue() == "" & sourceSheet.getRange(row,8).getValue() >= "45"){
 Logger.log("CELL H"+row+" has \">=45\""+"\n=================\n"+"CELL A"+row+" is \"empty\""+"\n=================\n"+"RANGE TO COPY:\n"+ "\"G"+row+":G"+row+"\"");
      var rangeToCopy = "G"+row+":G"+row;
      sourceSheet.getRange(rangeToCopy).copyTo(destination.getRange(destination.getLastRow()+1, 1)),{contentsOnly:true};
      destination.getRange(destination.getLastRow(), 9).setValue("Added Text Column 9");
      destination.getRange(destination.getLastRow(), 13).setValue("Added Text Column 13");
      destination.getRange(destination.getLastRow(), 14).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Also, there are other columns in Target sheet that fetch values so maybe that's the reason why the script isn't pasting on the right place but I can't get it to work.

Could you be so kind to help out?
Thank you in advance.

This is [a test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QmaZ2UYn3C34bq5j5Z_N8wjDNRbfFhyz7q88nx8qYEk/edit#gid=0) which returns the previously mentioned error when running the script.

**UPDATE**

I've added to the script:

```
var column = destination.getRange('A' + destination.getMaxRows())
      var lastFilledRow = column.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getA1Notation().slice(1)
      Logger.log(lastFilledRow);
```

so I would get the last filled row number in Column A. It retrieves it but I'm having trouble in using it as range and I get the error: *Exception: Cannot convert 'Range' to int.*

```
sourceSheet.getRange(rangeToCopy).copyTo(destination.getRange(destination.getRange(lastFilledRow,1), 1)),{contentsOnly:true};
```

Comment: Please provide a sample spreadsheet that generates the same error as well as the expected output.

Comment: @JasonE. I've added a test sheet as close as possible to the original. Thank you for your interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with your TARGET sheet having a set maximum row of 84, thus, `destination.getLastRow()+1` will return 85 which is outside the said maximum row.

[image]

To solve this, create a new TARGET sheet or find a way to remove the limit in the current TARGET sheet. Your current code should be fine.

EDIT:

I've edited your v2 code to make it work on the current test sheet provided. Please see code below.

```
   function CopyTo_V2(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("SOURCE");
  var destination = sheet.getSheetByName("TARGET");
  var lastRow = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();
  var column = destination.getRange('A' + destination.getMaxRows())

  for(var row=3; row<=lastRow; row++){
  if(sourceSheet.getRange(row,1).getValue() == "" & sourceSheet.getRange(row,8).getValue() >= "45"){
 Logger.log("CELL H"+row+" has \">=45\""+"\n=================\n"+"CELL A"+row+" is \"empty\""+"\n=================\n"+"RANGE TO COPY:\n"+ "\"G"+row+":G"+row+"\"");
      var rangeToCopy = "G"+row+":G"+row;
      var lastFilledRow = parseInt(column.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getA1Notation().slice(1))
      Logger.log(lastFilledRow);
      sourceSheet.getRange(rangeToCopy).copyTo(destination.getRange(lastFilledRow+1,1)),{contentsOnly:true};
      destination.getRange(lastFilledRow+1, 9).setValue("Added Text Column 9");
      destination.getRange(lastFilledRow+1, 13).setValue("Added Text Column 13");
      destination.getRange(lastFilledRow+1, 14).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try simplifying what you want and built it little by little so that it's easier for you to debug.  If you don't learn to debug your own code you'll be useless.

Comment: Thank you @Cooper for your insights. I've been trying the debug and with testing, as I've mentioned in my post's updated version, I understood that the +1 was a problem but what I can't still do is to make the script paste the values in the TARGET sheet after the last non empty row. When it kind of works, it pastes on the last empty row

Comment: @Whoopcg it pastes on the last empty row because of the set limit of row in the sheet making it return the last row(regardless if empty or not) when using getLastRow(). You can try using your script on a newly created sheet to test it out further.

Comment: @JasonE. I understood the problem is getLastRow(). Original sheet has 2000 rows and the problem is the same. I don't know how to retrieve the last non empty row as I thought it would work with getLastRow. After reading several other posts, I did a new version that fetches the last filled row number: `var column = destination.getRange('A' + destination.getMaxRows())
  var lastFilledRow = column.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getA1Notation().slice(1)` but I'm getting the error: "Exception: Cannot convert 'Range' to int" when trying to use it as range. I've added the code as V2.

Comment: @Whoopcg I've edited my answer to provide a solution for v2 code. The exception you are getting is because you probably missed that you are trying to add a range in the row parameter of your copyTo() code. Nevertheless, please see my answer and see if it works for you.

Comment: @JasonE. It works! Yes, I was. Thank you so much for the help and in the process I've also learned about the "parseInt" you used.